# AutoML Tables Batch Prediction- lost records

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl

I uploaded a file with 4000 records for batch prediction. The data  contains 86 variables and it's a binary classification task. I specified Cloud Storage as my output destination. The batch prediction returned CSV file with only 3730 records. I wonder why some records are missing in the output. The error file was empty so I have no idea. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you're experiencing may occur when some of your input data is corrupted, missing, or otherwise in a format incompatible with your model. Complete requirements can be found on [preparing your training data](https://cloud.google.com/automl-tables/docs/prepare) page.

Thus, I would recommended you to check that your input files, else your model will continue to generate the errors. Additionally, have a look on the following [paragraphs](https://cloud.google.com/automl-tables/docs/beginners-guide#clean_up_missing_incomplete_and_inconsistent_data): `Clean up missing, incomplete, and inconsistent data` and `Analyze your data after importing`:

> You should also review each column's nullability, which determines
> whether a column can have missing or NULL values.

Additionally, if the batch size is large, there might be more failed predictions than you expect.

Answer (score -1):

I am having the same issue - missing predictions and an empty errors table. I am loading csv from GCS.
I have verified that the columns are Nullable. I do have mixed types `str` and `np.nan` in the nullable columns. Could that be the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: This answer do not fundamentally answer the question. The answer is asking another, different question. Should be posted as a different question.